# Progress OpenEdge Developer Studio - Missing OpenEdge tab in toolbar & No Default servers

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I attempted to install the OpenEdge Developer Studio ver11.5 32bit in my laptop to complete some training assignments. After the installation, I compared mine with my colleague and the training tutorial. The Developer Studio I installed is missing the OpenEdge tab in toolbar and the default AppServer. My colleague and I did the exact steps during the installation. Can someone please let me know what the issue is? How can I connect to the default AppServer? It have to connect to the default AppServer in order for me to work on the training assignment.

My Developer Studio:

[Screenshot from local version / Windows>Preferences>Progress OpenEdge>StartUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htWn2.jpg)

[Screenshot from local version / Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SqYC.jpg)

Comment: How does your Help -> About ... dialog look like? Does that contain the developer studio icon?

Comment: It has 6 icons: eclipse modeling project, eclipse web tools platform, progress software corporation, eclipse.org, and progress software corporation

Comment: Can you do Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> OpenEdge Server ?

Answer (score 1):

To add the default servers go to: Window -> Preferences then navigate to Progress OpenEdge -> Server -> OpenEdge Explorer. Edit the Explorer 1 connection and enter your Admin Server user and password (may be admin/admin). Then "Test Connection" and "Create Servers & Finish".

Comment: I tested the connection before posting. It was connected successfully. The issue for this part is that I don't have AppServer listed in OpenEdge Explorer.

Comment: Which is why you should add the default servers from the preferences.

Comment: In my explorer 1 connection, it has the admin server username and password. Are you saying I need to save the explorer 1 again myself in Preferences?

Comment: You need to hit the "Create Servers & Finish" button in that dialog.

Comment: I see. I will try that later. Wish me luck.do you have an idea why my local version is missing the OpenEdge tab?

Comment: See my comment above. You should try to open an OpenEdge related perspective.

Comment: By doing Window -> Open Perspective -> Other -> OpenEdge Server, It solved my second question. The OpenEdge tab is now available. I did hit the "Create Servers & Finish" button in Server. But it still said "No AppServer is available in the current workspace." In my OpenEdge Resources, it only have AminServer and Collection.

Comment: Go to http://localhost:9090 to test if the Armin server is running and verify if you actually got any AppServers.

Comment: how to test if the Admin Server is running and how to verify if I have any AppServers? It brought me to the OpenEdge Explorer page by going to localhost:9090.

Comment: Alrighty... In localhost:9090, There is nothing listed under Resources / OpenEdge / Pacific Application Server. Also, there is nothing listed under Resources / OpenEdge / OE Web Server.

Comment: That explains why the "Create servers & Finish" does not add any servers ... not sure why you don't have the default servers. They are typically created by the install process. If you haven't done much with your OE installation yet, it might be easiest to re-install.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. Re-install may not work neither. I tried it several time before posting this question.